# Primefaces KeyFilter not working in Chrome

Tags: primefaces, keyfilter

I am using Primefaces KeyFilter with alphanum mask. It is working fine in IE but not working in Chrome.
Here is my sample xhtml.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 

    </h:head>   
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="projectKey"  label="Project Key" size="29" maxlength="10">
            </h:inputText>
            <p:keyFilter for="projectKey" mask="alphanum" />
        </h:form>
    </html>
```

As per the keyFilter, it should not allow to enter any special characters in the input box. It is working fine in IE but not in Chrome.

Comment: I am using Primefaces 6.1

Comment: Works for me: Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit) OS X.